# linux kernel development

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm very much interested in linux kernel development.
But I have no prior knowledge about linux architecture and all.
where to start with. please help me to find out the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to start with [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468) book.

Also good site to start is [Kernel Newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/).

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the source code.
2. Join the developer mailing list and ask for a simple task to solve.

PS: Sorry, can't add links because kernel.org is down for maintenance.

Comment: thank you for ur valuable information sir.And I have one more doubt,I heard like while implementing our own linux flavour then just do it on a virtual machine.Why it is so said and what is all about?

Comment: Because if you make a mistake, the PC on which Linux is running will freeze. If that is your only PC, how do you plan to debug the problem? If your development version runs in a virtual machine, you can at least dump the memory to a file on your real PC and analyze it.

Comment: ya now I got it.which virtual machine I can prefer?

Comment: I use VirtualBox because it's free. If you use Windows, VirtualPC should be free as well for personal use.

Comment: From your comment I inferred that, a Linux kernel can also be developed in a Windows environment, using the gc++ compiler.Is that right?

Comment: Maybe but I'm not sure whether this is a good thing for a newbie to try - there any many subtle differences between Windows and Linux, especially when it comes to building software. You might fare better by deploying a working/existing Linux distro in a VM and work in there and use a second VM to try the results. RAM is cheap.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to "Linux Kernel Development" by Robert Love, you'll find http://www.makelinux.com/books/ulk3/ (check out also [other resources](http://www.makelinux.com/resources)). Check out also [Kernel Newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHacking).

Comment: thank you for your valuable information