# How to find where older version of GLIB has been installed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, glib

I am trying to install `atk-2.4.0` and I get the error:

```
 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.32.3, but GLIB (2.26.1)
*** was found!
```

I also tried updating `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to include the path of `glib-2.0.pc` but still same error appears. Could anyone help me how to find where 2.26.1 was installed I am relatively new to Ununtu? Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of this operation - `find /usr/ -iname "*glib*.pc"`? And `dpkg -l libglib2.0-dev`?

Comment: `dpkg -l libglib2.0-dev
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  libglib2.0-dev 2.26.1-0ubuntu Development files for the GLib library`

Comment: @another.anon.coward `find /usr/ -iname "*glib*.pc"
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/glib-sharp-2.0.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc`

Comment: So you have `glib` version `2.26.1` installed through Ubuntu repositories but also you have installed version `2.32.2` from source (this is a guess based on the path being `/usr/local/` which is the default configured path. So which version of `glib` do you need to use? What have you set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` & `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as?

Comment: @another.anon.coward they were both empty, I guess I didn't set them correctly last time. But this time I set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` and wasn't sure what to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to. I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: If you need version `2.32.2` set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` (which you have) & `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib/`

Comment: @another.anon.coward Awesome, thank you. Do you know some good book or some other resource that I could use to better understand the kernel structure and the installation process, I have good programming foundation but know nothing about the kernel. By the way you could post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: This SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363084/linux-kernel-development might give you pointers regarding kernel development, I am sorry but I am not qualified enough to suggest something on my own :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posting comments as response:
From `find /usr/ -iname "*glib*.pc"` it is found that there `.pc` file related to `glib` is available in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` & `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. Checking the system package management it appears that version `2.26.1` is installed from the repositories. The path for installation of `glib` from repositories is *generally* `/usr/lib` (This may vary a bit in case of 64 bit systems wherein there are different folders for 32 bit & 64 bit libraries). Thus it appears that `glib` also has been installed from source (guessing by installation path `/usr/local/lib`) which of version `2.32.2`. If you need version `2.32.2` set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` & `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib/`
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer saved my time!

Answer (score 5):

You have to synchronize you `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables. Assuming that your prefix is `/usr/local` the followings should be set:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

You may also need to set other variables to compile glib dependent softwares:

```
ACLOCAL_PATH=/usr/local/share/aclocal/
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```